# Are there a good examples of using 'scala.swing'?

Tags: swing, scala, scala-2.8, scala-swing

I don't know Java or [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29), but I'm quite familiar with Scala, and I have no problems using it for my purposes. But when I try to implement a GUI, I get a lot of problems/bugs that documentation can't easily solve. I guess [scala.swing](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/swing/package.html) examples could help a lot!

Are there any small but not trivial and well written applications using scala.swing that I could learn from?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are many good examples in [sources](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/swing/scala/swing/test). I recommend checking it out.

Also, Ingo posted a [nice intro](http://ingomaier.blogspot.com/2010/11/scalaswing-package-in-28-and-beyond.html) to the scala.swing design.

I found that reading the sources wasn't so hard and helped a lot.

Comment: Here is another source: http://otfried.org/scala/gui.html

Answer (score 5):

Here's a short [presentation by Ken Scambler](http://vimeo.com/13900342) ([slides here](http://www.slideshare.net/perneto/scalaswing)) in which he explains the basic idea of scala.swing and does some nice tricks using mixin composition to paint components.

Answer (score 4):

The official [scala.swing description](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/sids/imaier/Mon,%202009-11-02,%2008:55/scala-swing-design.pdf) has a number of good examples. Also, there are examples in the *[Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala)* book by Martin Odersky and others.

Comment: That linked resource not found.  Might be [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/sids/imaier/Mon,%202009-11-02,%2008:55/scala-swing-design.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The last chapter (Ch. 33) in Odersky's [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala) goes through the process of making a simple, but certainly non-trivial GUI spreadsheet program using Scala. It's a pretty rich GUI application and the source (as well as explanation) is all there. The chapter before it details GUI programming using scala.swing and is full of examples, but it doesn't have very many complete ones.

Scala isn't used too heavily in creating desktop applications, but it certainly can be done. If you want a GUI with a Scala application, [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) definitely does the trick (it's used in its Java form in a number of popular desktop applications, like [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), and scala.swing is just a wrapper for javax.swing).

Comment: Note that `scala.swing` has been significantly changed in Scala 2.8, while the first edition of _Programming in Scala_ documents 2.7.

Comment: @Alexey the second edition is coming out soon which retains the spreadsheet example and is Scala 2.8 specific.

Comment: Actually Eclipse is SWT but Intellij is Swing

Answer (score 0):

scala.swing comes with examples, likely matching "small but not trivial". This is a link to the [GitHub home of Scala Swing, /test folder](https://github.com/ingoem/scala-swing/tree/master/scala/swing/test).

It's not enough, but it is the best start.

The Stack Overflow question *[Tutorial on Swing in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893610/tutorial-on-swing-in-scala)* has a reply pointing to [a German tutorial](http://scalatutorial.de/topic31.html), with examples (no need to speak German, keep pushing the buttons).

[This tetrix example](http://eed3si9n.com/tetrix-in-scala/swing.html) is not trivial but GUI-simple.

*[package root](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala-swing/#package)* is not answering the question directly, but in these circumstances the API is a good start.